# Regex - Разбить строку 2aab13c на подстроки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Прошу подсказать, как разбить строку **2aab13c** на подстроки **2aab** и **13c**.

Пробовал так:

```
import re

print(re.match(r'(\d+\w+)', '2aab13c'))
```

но не сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

```py
re.findall(r'\d+\D*', text)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/oW3Qcb/1/).
**Подробности**

- `\d+` - одна и более цифр
- `\D*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от цифр.

Ещё один вариант - это использование `re.split`:

```py
re.split(r'(?<=\D)(?=\d)', text)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/oW3Qcb/2). `(?<=\D)(?=\d)` находит позиции в строке между нецифровым и цифровым символами.

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/jKt96j).